# Accessing a self-executing function

Tags: javascript

How can I access the function alert from within it's enclosing function?

> (function() {
>
> function alert(){ console.log("alert"); }
>
> })();

e.g, this does not work ofc -

> (function() {
>
> function alert(){ console.log("alert"); }
>
> })();
>
> alert();

Comment: `alert` is reserved. Once you scope your function off with a self-executing function, you cannot access it outside the self-executing function, unless you assign an Anonymous function to a var and have it at a higher scope that the self-executing function. The keyword `this` can be used to refer to the function itself, but you need to call a new instance.

Comment: You cannot. It's only defined in the scope it was defined in.

Comment: not even event-dispatchers/listeners? It's completely innaccessible now?

Comment: Local symbols you don't expose explicitly are unreachable as soon as you leave a scope.

Comment: Completely inaccessible. It's like it's in a cave, deep underground, and surrounded by robot tigers and tiny stinging lizards who really don't like you.

Comment: @Nicholas Kyriakides: "but will it blend?" --- "this does not work ofc". Haven't you answered yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must export it to the outside.

For example,

```js
var publicAlert;
(function() {
    function alert(){ console.log("alert"); }
    publicAlert = alert;
})();
publicAlert();
```

```js
var publicAlert = (function() {
    function alert(){ console.log("alert"); }
    return alert;
})();
publicAlert();
```